# Add audio attachment link to RSS

Tags: attachments, rss, audio

This is how I'm adding a featured image to my RSS:

```
function featuredtoRSS($content) {
global $post;
if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
$content = '' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'topImage', array( 'style' =>  'margin:0 auto; border: 1px solid #555; display:block;' ) ) . '' . $content;
}
return $content;
}

add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'featuredtoRSS');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'featuredtoRSS');
```

All of my posts have audio attachments (one per post), and I would like to add them to RSS as well. How would I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this part into your function:

```
$audios =& get_children('post_type=attachment&post_parent='.$post->ID.'&post_mime_type=audio' );
foreach ( $audios as $id => $audio ){ 
    $content.='<a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($id).'" target="_blank">'.$audio->post_title.'</a> ';
}
```

to add audio links into your feed content.

I'm using `get_children()` here, you can read more about it here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children

**Edit:**

Here is the whole function:

```
function featuredtoRSS($content) {
    global $post;

    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
        $content = '' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'topImage', array( 'style' =>  'margin:0 auto; border: 1px solid #555; display:block;' ) ) . '' . $content;
    }

    $audios =& get_children( 'post_type=attachment&post_parent='.$post->ID.'&post_mime_type=audio' );
    foreach ( $audios as $id => $audio ){ 
        $content.='<a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($id).'" target="_blank">'.$audio->post_title.'</a> ';
    } 

    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'featuredtoRSS');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'featuredtoRSS');
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you please help me assemble the whole function?

Comment: sure, I added the updated function above.

Comment: Yep, that's how I did it initially (thank you very much though). There's a problem though: this is what WP adds to the feed:

    <a target="_blank" href="<a href='http://domain.com/correct-link-to.mp3' title='post title'>post title</a>" xml:base='http://domain.com/path/to/feed/'>post title</a>

Comment: I've figured it out, one needs to use wp_get_attachment_url instead of wp_get_attachment_link.

Comment: ok great ;-) I will update the code example.